# Locally developed nuget with dependent projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Let's say I have project *A* and project *B*. Project *A* depends on project *B*. So *A* would normally have a direct reference to *B*'s DLL.

Then I decided to publish *B* as a nuget package. Now, *A* has a reference to *B* via nuget instead of a local DLL.

The downside to this arrangement is that if I update *B*, I need to upload a new nuget and wait for it to be available in order to use it from *A*.

I see that I can point to a local nuget package when updating *A*'s reference to *B* so that does help a bit. However, if I make a change to *B*, I do still have to go through the steps of generating a new package and updating *A*'s reference to the package before *A* will see the change. With the pre-nuget arrangement, I simply built *B* and *A* would see the changes.

An alternative is to remove *A*'s reference to *B*'s nuget package and revert to pointing to the local DLL while doing local development. However, if *A* is published to github, then the reference has to be reverted to a nuget reference before pushing to github.

What's the best practice in a situation like this? Surely many folks are dealing with this sort of thing with github and nuget being widely used.

---

**UPDATE**

This topic came up for [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/bjid8z/locally_developed_nuget_with_dependent_projects/) on the C# subreddit and some interesting approaches were pointed out.

## Azure devops - [original comment - thanks to B0dona](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/bjid8z/locally_developed_nuget_with_dependent_projects/em8jrje/)

> What we do is use azure devops (
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/ ) to build and push
>   our nuget packages to our own repository (nuget.org is slow)
>   automatically after a new commit has been pushed.
>
> You set it up once, push project B drink some coffee and enjoy the joy
>   that is updating packages.

## git submodules - [original comment - thanks to alkrun](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/bjid8z/locally_developed_nuget_with_dependent_projects/em8wup8/)

> You mention GitHub so I'll propose something a bit different:
>
> In my opinion, if work on project A is likely to cause changes in
>   project B, A referencing B as a git submodule is much easier than
>   dealing with nuget. Git Submodules aren't without their headaches, but
>   this is what they were designed for. Some of the benefits:
>
> 1) The biggest is that if you say "If I need to change B then I'll
>   just make the change and push to get a new package built then test it
>   out in A" it's not a very fluid model to work with and it's asking
>   developers to push untested code into B. Then that 1-3 minute turn
>   around for CI build/package turns into 3 x 1-3 minute turnarounds and
>   it just feels horrible when I've tried it in the past. It's a massive
>   productivity killer.
>
> 2) Any other options around changing csproj files, they can work, but
>   they're very error prone. Developers aren't always great about
>   reviewing all changes before they commit them, you're going to have
>   developers forgetting and checking in the change to a project
>   reference and it's going to cause build failures.
>
> 3) Using B as a submodule for A doesn't prevent you from having
>   automated builds on B that produce nuget packages, and maybe other
>   projects which are less likely to change B could/should refer to those
>
> 4) At some point in the development of A, if it matures and becomes
>   less likely to cause changes in B, then you can switch A->B to a nuget
>   package reference also
>
> Another option, I remember reading an article years ago where someone
>   had created a tool that generated an msbuild xproj file that would
>   replace package references with project references. They had it set up
>   where the xproj file was on the .gitignore and if the file didn't
>   exist, the nuget package reference was used. In this way, a developer
>   would run a command to switch over to project references, make the
>   changes they need, commit them, push changes, then update the nuget
>   reference. This seemed fairly clean to me, but I can't find the
>   article and it was a bit more complicated than I'm making it sound.
>
> So I'd still go with the git submodule route. There are some quirks
>   with git submodules but they have gotten a lot easier to deal with in
>   the last couple years and it feels like the quirks are easier to
>   explain than the other options. Having used this for a few projects
>   now, it's very intuitive. Understand what a Git Submodule in a
>   detached head state is and how to avoid it, make sure to use the -b
>    option when adding a submodule, and find a good tool that can
>   handle submodules well. For what it's worth, VS Code is the most
>   intuitive interface I've found for working with submodules. Open A in
>   VS Code then switch to the version control tab and you'll see A and
>   any submodules listed up top along with the branches they're tracking.
>   Commit changes to the submodule, then to the parent and you're good to
>   go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch between nuget and project references effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140556/how-to-switch-between-nuget-and-project-references-effectively)

Comment: Are the two projects in the same repository?

Comment: @zivkan They are not in the same github repository.

Comment: in that case I disagree with "So A would normally have a direct reference to B's DLL". How would that even work? are you using submodules? I would expect it normal to use a NuGet package. In fact, even if in the same repo, you would use a project reference, not a direct reference to the dll.  But I don't have a suggestion to your issue, other than consider moving them into the same repo if possible. We had the same situation in a previous team and it was a productivity drain. I'd temporarily make it a project reference for development, but final checking was a two step process as you described

Answer (score 3):

The Node community demonstrates a more robust approach. The **[npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)** command which is available out of the box (see also [this blog post](https://www.deadcoderising.com/how-to-smoothly-develop-node-modules-locally-using-npm-link)), creates symbolic link from distributed package directory to package source directory. In this way:

- package consumers are transparently redirected to package source project
- changes in package sources are automatically reflected on the consumer side

The `npm link` approach has also these advantages over reference switching:

- no changes are made to consumer's source code -- which can accidentally be committed.
- works cross-platform, doesn't need a specific IDE
- can be scripted and shared with the team

This feature is obviously required in the NuGet community, but for some reason, NuGet still lacks it. There is a feature request https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1821, which indicates they have no plans of adding it.

Meanwhile I created a tool, which works similarly to **npm link** for NuGet packages, you may want to give it a try: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuLink

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017, you can install [NuGet Reference Switcher for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RicoSuter.NuGetReferenceSwitcherforVisualStudio2017) extension. Here is a guide how to use it: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NuGetReferenceSwitcher/wiki/Guide

Comment: Sounds useful, but only if one is not using "new-style" csproj format. As soon as presented with my VS solution, it complained I use new-style projects and went no further.