# Use project reference or NuGet conditionally

Tags: visual-studio, github, nuget, github-actions

I have a bunch of class library projects with their own GitHub repositories along with GitHub Actions workflows to generate their NuGet packages. There are also interdependencies among these projects. For example, `MyApp.Infrastructure` depends on `MyApp.Core` library. Also `MyApp.Business` depends on both `MyApp.Core` *and* `MyApp.Infrastructure`.

Some combination of these class libraries are used by multiple front end and backend applications. That's why it's important that each class library references its dependencies through NuGet packages because when they're used in my apps, just adding one of these NuGet packages should automatically take care of its own dependencies.

This all works fine in production but while I work on these class libraries, I use them in a solution and using project references instead of NuGet package references speeds up the development process significantly.

Is there a way to create conditional blocks in `csproj` files so that during development project references are used but when I check the code into their respective GitHub repositories, their NuGet references would be used by GitHub Actions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch between nuget and project references effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140556/how-to-switch-between-nuget-and-project-references-effectively)

Comment: This got me pretty close but I'm still not 100% there. First, the Visual Studio extensions don't work with VS 2022 so that was out of the question. Using `Conditions` work but not for `Debug` , `Release` because GitHub actions were still failing. However, switching to `Exists` for project folders did the trick i.e `<ItemGroup Condition="Exists('../../ProjectA/Project.csproj')">`. The only problem I have now is that I reference all my class libraries in an ASP.NET Core project and GitHub action for it is still failing because the projects are referenced in the solution `.sln` file. Suggestions?

Comment: I dont understand why you don't leave them as project references all the time. When you pack the project, project references get turned into package dependencies too.

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing the obvious here but there are two requirements I need to meet: each class library project has its own GitHub repo and uses GitHub actions to generate its NuGet. The second requirement is that these class libraries can be used in a number of combinations. Some projects need only `A`, some need `A` and `B`, some may need `A`, `C` and `D` so those projects that need these class libraries should simply get the packages they need. Further more some class libraries depend on each other. For example `B` may need `A`. Do you think I can achieve this by just referencing projects?